# in shockwave object while running flex application using c# pop up alert message is not displaying properly of form when form is minimized

Tags: .net, windows, flash, activex, shockwave

I have created one windows application on .net framework using c# for running Adobe flex application using Active X flash object. it is working fine and there is no issue except when window form is minimized and application is running in it and if any pop up alert come then it is going on top left corner of form and if window is in normal or maximized mode same alert is displaying in middle of application. sometimes alert is displaying in inside window but outside border of form. please help..

here is c# code i have written for running flash application

```
        AxShockwaveFlash ax = new AxShockwaveFlash(); 
        ax.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            ax.AllowNetworking = "all";
            ax.AllowScriptAccess = "always";
            ax.DisableLocalSecurity();
            ax.LoadMovie(0, applicationUrl);
```

Comment: Are you talking about a pop from the Flex / SWF app? Most likely it checks its container size (width & height) and calculates "middle", but if your C# app (the container) is minimized then size becomes zero which gives output coords of "top-left" to the SWF and it thinks that's the middle. You have to edit the AS3 source code that produced the SWF and recompile.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. But same scenario is working fine when application is running in IE.. But ok i will try what you suggested.

Comment: Try to load the SWF through C#'s web Browser and see if that helps?

Comment: I tried but output is same as windows..

Comment: Well IE and C# webBrowser are supposed to be the same engine giving same results but regarding your SWF then `IExplore.exe` must be doing something special. Can you create a simple SWF that recreates this pop-up problem for testing?

Comment: my finding is when swf file is embedded in html then alert is displaying properly though screen is minimized.. but i am running swf file under windows form.. please let me know if any setting that i can try to resolve issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [VC.One](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057709/vc-one) for your response. your first comment given me answer. sorry for late posting. issue was i made "Docktype=fill" for flash object so whenever screen minimize the size of flash object also decreased so based on that size eg.100,20 alert displayed on 0,0 location. So now removed "Docktype=fill" and maintaining original screen size. My application is working fine now

Thank you.